# Predictive Performance of Random Forest: Is there a difference between permuting or run the model without the permuted variable?

Tags: r, performance, random-forest

I'm using the R package "ModelMap" to produce Random Forest (RF) models (regression model). It provides a plot showing relative importance of input variables, by measuring the decrease of MSE in % of the overall accuracy of the model for input variable xy after permuting = eliminating its predictive ability. Another plot shows the RMSE of the model, based on model validation using the test data (predicted values vs. observed values).

Now lets produce another RF model excluding the mentioned input variable xy and lets compare the RMSE with the RMSE of the first model. The result **almost 0** (the unit is for each ca 300 kg/ha ) even though the decrease of MSE of the previous model showed a decrease of 70% for variable xy and should lead to a decrease in performance by excluding it.

Does this approach make sense? And if yes, why does the 2nd model has the same predictive performance?

Thanks for help

Comment: Sounds like you're model isn't generalizable. Or you have highly correlated predictors--see Strobl et al (2007)

Comment: Also, I've voted to move to CV

Comment: Does anybody know if after permuting the variable the model is reproduced (including the eliminated variable xy) or is the permuted variable used to go through the decisions of the same model? @Alex thanks for the comment, the data is not correlated, but the model works well by excluding some of the predictor variables! What do you mean with CV?

Comment: VI is computed by running the observations down the trees after permutation. No variables are removed

Comment: Thanks Alex. I think this explains my problem since the approach to compare (i) the increase of MSE after permuting a certain variable with (ii) the RMSE of the model (the same variable excluded) does not make sense, because latter model is built without and first with the PV and are thus simply not comparable.